# How to send IPv6 packets from different addresses under my prefix?

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking, ipv6

I am trying to figure out how to make use of all of the addresses I have on my VPS with a /64 ipv6 prefix. However, when I try to send messages they always exit via the address assigned to the interface, I can't figure out how to get them to leave via a specific IP.

Here is my ifconfig output for the relevant interface:

```
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 51.x.y.z  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::i:j:k:1c0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2607:a:b:c::55  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether fa:16:l:m:n:o  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

When I check my IPv6 via CLI I clearly get:

```
# curl icanhazip.com
2607:a:b:c::55
```

If my understanding is correct 2607:a:b:c:1::55 is also an IP under my range. How would I send a message via that IP? My expected result would then be:

```
# curl icanhazip.com
2607:a:b:c:1::55
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use a different IPv6 address for a one-shot job or a short period, you can simply add (or change) an IP address using the `ip` command eg:

```
ip addr add 2607:a:b:c:1::55 dev eth0 valid_lft 120 preferred_lft 120
```

In this example you add an IP address to interface eth0 with a lifetime of just 2 minutes.

You can also tell Curl to use a specific interface/outbound IP address using the [`--interface`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--interface) option.
Also have a look at the `valid_lft` & `preferred_lft` directives.

Comment: I was hoping to assign multiple addresses permanently. This method means my original IP address isn't usable while the other is active.

Comment: You can of course have multiple addresses enabled. This is just an example. There are different ways to set this up in Linux, like for example virtual interfaces. Then you have to tell programs which IP address/interface to use or they will fall back on a default/random one.

Comment: So something like `ip link add dev virtual0 type <something>` then `ip addr add IPv6/prefix dev virtual0`?